# Numpy - Extracting Unique Values from a Distance Matrix

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, scipy

## Input Data:

I have the following `distance_matrix`:

```
  [[1.        , 0.14285714, 0.25      , 0.83333333, 0.63636364],
   [0.14285714, 1.        , 0.33333333, 0.84615385, 0.66666667],
   [0.25      , 0.33333333, 1.        , 0.76923077, 0.58333333],
   [0.83333333, 0.84615385, 0.76923077, 1.        , 0.69230769],
   [0.63636364, 0.66666667, 0.58333333, 0.69230769, 1.        ]]
```

## Current Results:

`np.where(distane_matrix <= 0.25)` returns the following output:

`(array([0, 0, 1, 2]), array([1, 2, 0, 0]))`

## Desired Results:

`(array([0, 0]), array([1, 2]))`

## Explanation:

To put this into words, since I know that:

1. `[0,1]` has the same value as `[1,0]`
2. `[0,2]` has the same value as `[2,0]`
3. `[0,1]` and `[0,2]` satisfy the requirements of `np.where()`

I do **not** want `[1,0]` and `[2,0]` to be returned in the output, since it is redundant information. What is the best way to do this?

Comment: That doesn't look much like a distance matrix, what with the 1s on the diagonal.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. It should be 0s on the diagonal. Nonetheless, I will keep the original post the same, so that the answers are more readable for future users.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming `d` is a specified distance matrix.

Demo:

```
In [28]: r = np.triu(d, 1)

In [29]: r
Out[29]:
array([[0.        , 0.14285714, 0.25      , 0.83333333, 0.63636364],
       [0.        , 0.        , 0.33333333, 0.84615385, 0.66666667],
       [0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.76923077, 0.58333333],
       [0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.69230769],
       [0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ]])

In [30]: np.where((r>0) & (r<=0.25))
Out[30]: (array([0, 0], dtype=int64), array([1, 2], dtype=int64))
```

Comment: Think OP wants `tril` indices?

Comment: @Divakar, a distance matrix is usually symmetrical, so the result shouldn’t differ...

Comment: Ah yeah that's right. What if there's a 0 in there?

Comment: @Divakar, that would mean that this is a distance for the same point, which is usually ignored...

Comment: @Divakar, i'm assuming that the distance is not interesting for such points

Answer (score 1):

If you want a solution independent of the selection criteria you may consider using a masked array:

```
import numpy.ma as ma

mat_masked = ma.array(your_mat, mask = np.triu(np.ones(np.shape(your_mat))))
```

From here you'd go on as before

```
np.where(mat_masked <= 0.25)
```

This has also the advantage that your data are left untouched.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an approach with `masking` -

```
def get_lower_indices(a, thresh=0.25):
    n = a.shape[0]    
    ra = np.arange(n)
    mask = ra[:,None] < ra
    v = np.flatnonzero(a[mask] <= thresh)
    idx = np.concatenate(( [0], np.arange(n-1,0,-1).cumsum() ))
    c = np.searchsorted(idx, v,'right')-1
    r = v-idx[c]+c+1    
    return c,r
```

Sample run -

```
In [116]: a
Out[116]: 
array([[1.        , 0.14285714, 0.25      , 0.83333333, 0.63636364],
       [0.14285714, 1.        , 0.33333333, 0.84615385, 0.66666667],
       [0.25      , 0.33333333, 1.        , 0.76923077, 0.58333333],
       [0.83333333, 0.84615385, 0.76923077, 1.        , 0.69230769],
       [0.63636364, 0.66666667, 0.58333333, 0.69230769, 1.        ]])

In [117]: get_lower_indices(a, thresh=0.25)
Out[117]: (array([0, 0]), array([1, 2]))
```

If you are okay with editing the upper triangular elements to some higher value, which won't be caught in the threshold operation, we can do something along these lines -

```
def get_lower_indices_mask_editing(a, thresh=0.25):
    n = a.shape[0]
    r = np.arange(n)
    a[r[:,None] >= r] = 1
    return np.where(a<=thresh)
```

Other approach(es) :

```
# @MaxU's soln
def triu_where(d):
    r = np.triu(d, 1)
    return np.where((r>0) & (r<=0.25))
```

Timings -

```
In [231]: # Setup random array with larger size and no zeros
     ...: np.random.seed(0)
     ...: N = 5000
     ...: data = np.random.rand(N,N)
     ...: data = data.dot(data.T)
     ...: data = (data - data.min())/(data.max() -data.min())
     ...: data[data==0] = 0.1
     ...: np.fill_diagonal(data,1)

# @MaxU's soln
In [232]: %timeit triu_where(data)
10 loops, best of 3: 174 ms per loop

In [233]: %timeit get_lower_indices(data, thresh=0.25)
1 loop, best of 3: 318 ms per loop

In [234]: %timeit get_lower_indices_mask_editing(data, thresh=0.25)
10 loops, best of 3: 150 ms per loop
```

Comment: In the question, the desired result is the indices in the upper triangle.  It is a trivial change, but why not match the desired result?

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser The desired result can also be thought of as in the lower triangle and the final output would be in col, row format. The way I am setting up the incremental "triangular" stepping array with `np.concatenate(( [0], np.arange(1,n).cumsum() ))` is just easier if I work with lower triangular elements.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser Upon closer inspection, it seemed the order would had been different. Edited with upper triangular region in focus.

Answer (score 0):

instead of using `np.triu`, just use `np.triu_indices`.  With `d` as the distance matrix:

```
def dist_thr(d, thr = .25):
    i, j = triu_indices(d.shape[0], 1)
    mask = d[i, j] < thr
    return i[mask], j[mask]
```